# Jquery plugin to calculate correlation coefficient

Tags: jquery, distribution, correlation

Is there any jquery plugin to calculate correlation coefficient, standard deviation and covariance. Please refer me the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need only simple stuff like covariance, correl, ..., [jsanalysis](http://code.google.com/p/jsanalysis/wiki/Documentation) should do the trick. For more advanced features, [jstat](http://www.jstat.org/) probably contains everything you need.